# start of capturing group and pattern capture multiple times

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I gave up. I am using PHP to match capture all `[A-Za-z0-9-.]{1,7}` inside EITHER parenthesis or square brackets.

I have the following reg expresion

`$pattern = /(?:(?:\(|\[)([A-Za-z0-9-.]{1,7})(?:\)|\]))/`

I cannot understand, why

```
$r->filename = Flood Control Geo Survey (Bali) (Indo) (2005) (V1.0) [acc].doc

if (preg_match($pattern, $r->filename, $matches)) {
    echo $r->filename, '<br />';
    echo '<pre>', var_dump($matches), '</pre><hr />';

}
```

Outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "(Bali)"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "Bali"
}
```

1. I cannot understand why `[0]` captured the opening parenthesis and closing parenthesis when my capture group is AFTER its declaration. `[1]` is correct and  what I need, why i still have `[0]`?
2. Why is it stopping?, there's still `(Indo)`, `(2005)`, `(V1.0)` and `[acc]`? Why are those not captured?
3. My desired output is:

   array() {
       [0]=>
       string(6) "Bali"
       [1]=>
       string(4) "Indo"
       [2]=>
       string(4) "2005"
       [3]=>
       string(4) "V1.0"
       [4]=>
       string(4) "acc"
   }

Can somebody please help? Thank you!

Comment: Group 0 always contains the whole match, the capturing groups start with 1. You might want to use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

Comment: [Read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php): _"$matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on."_

Comment: @SebastianProske i saw it, `[0]` array contains `(,[,),]` and `[1]` array contains the stripped one? I do not understand, is it built in that php function or that's how I built my pattern?

Comment: See @SebastianProske comment and use `preg_match_all` then use the first index, https://eval.in/674300.

Comment: That's how patterns are matched in pretty much every regex implementation I know.

Comment: thank you very much guys @SebastianProske if you will reply with `preg_match_all` I will label mark it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: @SebastianProske: it isn't always the case, for example in Python: `re.findall(r'abc(...)def', s)` returns only the list of capture groups, without the whole match.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte But all the other re methods that are used to match return a match object, which again stores the whole match in group 0.